# Why is the Nexus 5 landscape width 598px?

Tags: media-queries

So after some Googling, and trial and error, I've found out that (as far as media queries are concerned) the landscape width of the Nexus 5 is 598px.  I am just not sure why.

I believe the Nexus 5 resolution is 1080x1920 with a 3x pixel density.  Which would make me think that:

@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape)

Would target it, but I have to go down to

@media all and (min-width: 595px) and (orientation: landscape)

My question is why?

Comment: Does the UI take up any space when in landscape orientation?

Comment: Yeah I think that's it. After posting this I was looking at my phone. In landscape mode the home/back/apps buttons are on the right. I guess the space taken up by them isn't counted by the browser. Makes sense.

Comment: Be sure to try other browsers too, e.g. Firefox. I've seen other posts on here suggesting they calculate viewport sizes differently.